# Read from /dev/pts/5 and output to /dev/pts/6

Tags: python

Need to run a python script to do the following which i am doing manually right now for testing

```
cat /dev/pts/5
```

And then i need to echo this back to /dev/pts/6

```
echo <DATA_RECEIVED_FROM_5> > /dev/pts/6
```

I can't seem to get the python to actually read what is coming in from /dev/pts/5 and saving it to a list and then outputing one by one to /dev/pts/6 using echo

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess

seq = []
count = 1

while True:
    term = subprocess.call(['cat','/dev/pts/5'])

    seq.append(term)
    if len(seq) == count:
        for i in seq:
            subprocess.call(['echo',i,'/dev/pts/6'])
            seq = []
            count = count + 1
```

Comment: So what is the aim of your program? To generate a list of files within `/dev/pts/5` and print this list of files into `/dev/pts/6`?

Comment: Well the ultimate goal there is another program that is printing something every few seconds to /dev/pts/5 and i need to be monitoring that in order to be able to print the same thing its printing out on /dev/pts/5 to /dev/pts/6, this is for a proof of concept, but we need to see how this would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, and desired outcome, but to generate a list of filenames within `/dev/pts/5` and just save it as a `.txt` file in `/dev/pts/6` You should use the `os` module that comes standard with python. You can accomplish this task as such:

```
import os

list_of_files = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/dev/pts/5'):
    list_of_files.append([dirpath, dirnames, filenames])
with open('/dev/pts/6/output.txt', 'w+') as file:
    for file_info in list_of_files:
        file.write("{} -> {} -> {}".format(file_info[0], file_info[1], file_info[2]))
```

The output from this will likely be a bit much, but you can just apply some logic to filter out what you're looking for.

[`os.walk()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

## update

To read the data from an arbitrary file and write it to an arbitrary file (no extensions) is (if I understand correctly) pretty easy to do in python:

```
with open('/dev/pts/5', 'rb') as file: # use 'rb' to handle arbitrary data formats
    data = file.read()
with open(''/dev/pts/6', 'wb+') as file:
    # 'wb+' will handle arbitrary data and make file if it doesn't exist.
    # if it does exist it will be overwritten!! To append instead use 'ab+'
    file.write(data)
```

## third time is the charm

Following the example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) it looks like you need to run:

```
term = subprocess.run(['cat','/dev/pts/5'], capture_output=True)
print(term.stdout)
```

Where the important bit is `capture_output=True` and then you have to access the `.stdout` of the `CompletedProcess` object!

Comment: thank you very much, but i think i may have confused what i am trying to do, i need to cat /dev/pts/5, that is actually a file not a directory, so i need to cat what is in /dev/pts/5 and echo or write into /dev/pts/6 which is another file

Comment: @Mr39 So you have a file named `5` with no extension? And your goal is to copy the contents of this file to a file named `6` with no extension?

Comment: correct, /dev/pts/5 and 6 are actual serial connections, thats why they dont have extensions, but it needs to keep looking at the file and when something comes to it copy it instantly to /dev/pts/6

Comment: @Mr39 is that more what you are trying to do?

Comment: thank you again for the update, but here lies the issue for some reason which i can't explain why, when i try to open the file in python it doesn't work, but if i run a system command like cat to the file it works fine, so thats why i kept trying to run an external command within python and save the output to a variable, but not being able to successfully

Comment: Thanks again, only issue now is that capture_output is only available is python 3.7 i am running 3.5

Comment: @Mr39 According to my link `New in version 3.5.` I don't see the problem?